# Role of docker-in-docker (dind) service in gitlab ci

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

According to the official [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor), one way to enable `docker build` within `ci` pipelines, is to make use of the `dind` service (in terms of `gitlab-ci` [services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/services/)).

However, as it is always the case with ci jobs running on docker executors, the `docker:latest` image is also needed.

Could someone explain:

- what is the difference between the `docker:dind` and the `docker:latest` images?
- (most importantly): **why** are **both** the service and the docker image needed (e.g. as indicated [in this example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/docker/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml), linked to from the github documentation) to perform e.g. a `docker build` whithin a ci job? doesn't the `docker:latest` image (**within which the job will be executed**!) incorporate the docker daemon (and I think the `docker-compose` also), which are the tools necessary for the commands we need (e.g. `docker build`, `docker push` etc)?

Unless I am wrong, the question more or less becomes:

> Why a docker client and a docker daemon cannot reside in the same docker (enabled) container

Comment: Because search engines point here for *"docker:dind install git"*: You can use `docker:git` which builds on top of `docker:dind`, but with git installed.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

> what is the difference between the docker:dind and the docker:latest images?

- [`docker:latest`](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/157869f94ea90e2acb4d0f77045d99079ead821c/18.02/Dockerfile) contains everything necessary to connect to a docker daemon, i.e., to run `docker build`, `docker run` and such. It also contains the docker daemon but it's not started as its entrypoint.
- [`docker:dind`](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/157869f94ea90e2acb4d0f77045d99079ead821c/18.02/dind/Dockerfile) builds on `docker:latest` and starts a docker daemon as its entrypoint.

So, their content is almost the same but through their entrypoints one is configured to connect to `tcp://docker:2375` as a client while the other is meant to be used for a daemon.

> why are both the service and the docker image needed […]?

You don't need both. You can just use either of the two, start `dockerd` as a first step, and then run your `docker build` and `docker run` commands as usual like I did [here](https://gitlab.com/saraedum/sandbox/blob/dind/.gitlab-ci.yml); apparently this was the original approach in gitlab [at some point](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/dind/). But I find it cleaner to just write `services: docker:dind` instead of having a `before_script` to setup `dockerd`. Also you don't have to figure out how to start & install `dockerd` properly in your base image (if you are not using `docker:latest`.)

Declaring the service in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` also lets you swap out the docker-in-docker easily if you know that your runner is mounting its `/var/run/docker.sock` into your image. You can set the [protected variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#secret-variables) `DOCKER_HOST` to `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` to get faster builds. Others who don't have access to such a runner can still fork your repository and fallback to the `dind` service without modifying your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Comment: To add to @saraedum 's post, if I am not mistaken, if you specify the `DOCKER_HOST` var to be what the service expects which I think is `DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://${DOCKER_REGISTRY}__library__docker:2375"` (and you do __not__ mount it to the host's socket), this will __disable__ docker layer caching (just a sidenote on the actual differences on using vs not using the service)

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! A follow-up question, if the only difference is `docker:dind` has started docker daemon as entrypoint, why can't we use `docker:dind` directly as image? Is it because in the `docker:dind`, it is also configured to connect to `tcp://docker:2375` insteand of `tcp://localhost:2375`?

Comment: How do docker:latest and docker:dind share memory and CPU with the host node? trying to identify the bottleneck for https://forum.gitlab.com/t/k8s-build-helper-svc-0-not-leveraging-maximum-cpu-memory-of-host/95195

Answer (score -6):

The container will contain only things defined in a docker image. You know you can install anything, starting from a base image. 
But you can also install Docker (deamon and client) in a container, that is to say a Docker IN Docker (dind). So the container will be able to run other containers. That's why gitlab need this.

Comment: Yes, but how does the dind container have anything to do with the docker:latest container?  Does it run inside of it? The only explanation from gitlab is that services can be used to spin up and link in auxiliary containers like a db for instance. I’m not seeing how just having a dind container available and linked would change anything.

Comment: Yes docker is installed in the dind image. What is your problem exactly?