# Why docker image doesn't run "docker build"?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using gitlab ci, and sorry for the silly question, but why that code below doesn't work?

```
image: docker:stable

stages:
  - build

build-docker:
  stage: build
  script:
  - docker build -t my-image .
```

When I run a docker image of docker on my terminal I'm able to use these commands like `docker build`.

For the gitlab-ci above works, I've to add the `services: docker:dind`, but I don't really understand why, since I've an image that theoretically has the commands that I need.

Sry about my English, btw.

Thx in advance.

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280922/role-of-docker-in-docker-dind-service-in-gitlab-ci

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Role of docker-in-docker (dind) service in gitlab ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280922/role-of-docker-in-docker-dind-service-in-gitlab-ci)