# How to make Gitlab CI/CD run container with some custom variables?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

i have a job that starts android UI-tests on GitLab CI/CD. It somehow runs a container from image `android-uitests:1.0` from registry. I don't know where and how Gitlab CI/CD runs that image using command "docker run ...", but i need to extend that command and i want to pass some variables (or arguments) in this command.

Here below example of command that i want Gitlab to do:

```
docker run -d \
       -t \
       --privileged \
       -e "SNAPSHOT_DISABLED"="true" \
       -e "QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX"=1 \
       -e "WINDOW"="true" \
       --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
       -p 5555:5555 -p 5554:5554 -p 5901:5901 \
       --name emulator \
       android-uitest:1.0
```

this is a stage and its job with image

```
ui-tests:
  image: registry.myproject:5000/android-uitests:1.0
  stage: ui-tests
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - schedules
  when: manual
  script:
    - bash /run-emulator.sh
    - adb devices
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
    - adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
    - adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
    - adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
    - ./gradlew mobile:connectedDevDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.package=app.online.tests.uitests
  tags:
    - androidtest
```

So another words i want to configure that  "under the hood `docker run` command" that runs my image.

Tell me please how to do that?

Comment: did you find any solution to pass arguments in gitlab while running the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you're using a Docker container, I'll assume you're using [a Gitlab Runner on Docker executor mode](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html), which means you're essentially running a [similar script to this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#authenticating-with-registry-in-docker-in-docker) when you don't specify a docker image to run the CI job:

```
image: docker:19.03.13

variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

services:
  - docker:19.03.13-dind

script:
  - (your commands)
```

To understand what's going on, let's break it in multiple steps:

```
    image: docker:19.03.13
(...)
    services:
      - docker:19.03.13-dind
```

#### `docker-19.03.13-dind`, what's the difference to `docker:19.03.13`?

#### why is it a service instead of an image?

DIND means Docker-in-Docker, [this part](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) of Gitlab's documentation can explain it in further technical details, but what is important to understand from this part is what is a service on Gitlab's CI context and why they have to specify an additional Docker image when already using a Docker image as a default environment. When you write a `service` on Gitlab CI, [you are able to use its command while you're inside an existing container](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-a-service). *e.g. when you want to connect a PostgreSQL (database) container to a backend container you're building, but without having to set up a docker-compose or multiple containers.*

Using a docker service to run together with a docker image, it means you can directly use `docker run` within your job without any additional setup. [This previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280922/role-of-docker-in-docker-dind-service-in-gitlab-ci) explains this question further.

Back to your code, instead of deploying your registry image as a job directly:

```
ui-tests:
  image: registry.myproject:5000/android-uitests:1.0
```

You may want to first, build your container and upload it to your registry:

```
image: docker:19.03.12

services:
  - docker:19.03.12-dind

variables:
  # Use TLS https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#tls-enabled
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  - docker build $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
  - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

This snippet will build your Dockerfile in the root folder of your repository and upload it to your Gitlab private (*or public, if your project is set as public*) image registry. Now you can specify an additional job specifically to do what you want:

### Final example

```
image: docker:19.03.12
stages:
  - build
  - release
services:
  - docker:19.03.12-dind

variables:
  # Use TLS https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#tls-enabled
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest

deploy:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - docker run -d -t --privileged -e "SNAPSHOT_DISABLED"="true" -e "QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX"=1    -e "WINDOW"="true" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw"    -p 5555:5555 -p 5554:5554 -p 5901:5901 --name emulator $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

#### Why are you using `$VARIABLES`?

In case of an environment variable may sound confusing, [here's the list of default environment variables Gitlab generates for every job it creates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#list-all-environment-variables).

The last example I cited will result in a Docker container running in the same machine your executor is registered, with the environment variables you have specified.

If you need a practical example, [you can use this `gitlab-ci.yml` of a project of mine as reference](https://gitlab.com/gruberx/code-server/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml).

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed answer